# What does {:d} do?

Tags: python

So I understand that you can do, for example:

```
x = input("Enter an integer: ")
print("I am now printing variable x: {}".format(x))
```

To get the output of whatever string I put in there, as {} is simply the placeholder for the variable.

However, on a website I saw {:d} being used, and despite experimenting in Python to figure out what it does, I cannot seem to find its use. Why is {:d} used when printing the variable and what use does it have?

Comment: Please look at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html It's a format specifier.

Comment: This is a [Format Specifier](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-specifiers)

Comment: For string formatting I prefer to use https://pyformat.info over the normal docs. For the case of `{:d}`, which I agree is very hard to search for online, see [this section](https://pyformat.info/#number)

Answer (score 1):

In python you can specify the format inside the curved brackets.

You can do things such as

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(2)
'10'
```

In your case, d prints as decimal integer.

You can find all the doc here

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language